# Module 'image_picker_ios' not found Error when imported Flutter Project in Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter's [Image Picker Library](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) for picking images from gallery in flutter. It works completely fine in android but not in iOS. In Xcode, i added the flutter ios directory in the xcode and the project is not even building ... got the following error:

`Module 'image_picker_ios' not found`

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAK9Q.png)

I have followed the library's documentation provided in pub.dev where for iOS i was required to add few things in info.plist but still i am getting the same error.

```
name: test
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.2 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: 1.0.4
  image_picker_ios: 0.8.8+2
  get:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_svg: 2.0.7

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/

  fonts:
    - family: Helvetica
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/helveticabold.otf
    - family: HelveticaRegular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/helveticaregular.otf
    - family: HelveticaNeue
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/helveticaneue.ttf
```

I have added "image_picker" in dependencies but since i was getting the **Module 'image_picker_ios' not found** error, so i tried adding **image_picker_ios** as well but no use.

Any help would be highly appreciated.